# can I kill close_wait connection on weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, soa, netstat

On some bad days, our application server (Weblogic) tends to get a lot of CLOSE_WAIT sessions.
We have even gone to the extent of restarting our middleware weblogic suite in broadDaylight to get timely fixes since these cause kind of a panic situation.

$ netstat -nat | egrep 'CLOSE_WAIT' | wc -l
412.

Provided that these are just processes, is there a way to kill them without affecting the running of my server?

I came across this script which takes the host:port and claims to kill these sessions, but not sure if this will work on Production environment.

"$ netstat -anp | grep 192.168.0.100 | grep ':80 ' | grep CLOSE_WAIT | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d / -f1 | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}" | xargs kill"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are many reasons that can lead to too many sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state. Can you give more details about your architecture and configuration ?
Any HTTP front end server ? Which one ? Version ?
SSL ? 
WebLogic server version ? Clustering ?
etc...

Comment: Oracle Fusion Middleware, AIA O2C PIP, mostly CLOSE_WAIT with Siebel endpoints which are http connections (custom flows), WLS 10.3, 2Managed servers and 1 Admin server.